# Create functions inside adobe animate timeline (actions)

Tags: javascript, adobe, createjs

im trying to make a function work inside the main timeline of adobe animate canvas. I have that code:

```
function player(){
var power = 19;
}
console.log(this.power);
```

When i execute it , it says undefined.Can anyone explain me why?

Answer (score 3):

Inside your method `player()` your define a *local* variable `power` which only exist inside the scope of that function, elsewhere there is no such variable. So when you write you are actually referring to the *global* variable `window.power` (*`this` is the `window` in this case*) is not defined.

A final note when you correct this you still need to execute the function.

You can either define `power` globally or run the `console.log` inside your function where that variable is defined:

*First case:*

```js
var power;
function player() {
    power = 19;
}
player();
console.log(power);
```

*Second case:*

```js
function player(){
    var power = 19;
    console.log(power);
}
player();
```

*Note:*  Whenever you try to access a variable outside the scope of any functions it's accessing that `window` object as: `window.someVariable` so in this case you can just do `someVariable` as in the two examples above.

Comment: thanks for the quick respose. I think the "global object" when adobe flash animate exports the FLA , its the exportRoot object.And as i know objects are a collection of name and values , so creating a function it would be attatched to the exportRoot object.Having 'this' inside console.log doesnt redirects to the object that the function is beingh stored?

Comment: The global object is Window, the same as any other time you make an anonymous function. If you want the scope to be the clip you are in, then define your functions on it directly: `this.player = function() { this.power = 19; }`.

Comment: Oh ! As i have understand if you create a function you CANT access the varables inside of it from the global object , but you can access  variables that are in global object from functions , right?

Comment: @Β_origin That's correct for local variables you make with `var`. The local variables made inside the function only exist within that function, the second you leave it they are gone. Global variables on the other hand can be accessed anywhere and don't go away.

Answer (score 1):

The 'this' keyword refers to which object is calling a function, *not* the actual function itself.

For example:

> let player = {
>       func: function() {
>         console.log(this.power);
>       },
>       power: 10 }
>
> player.func();

//will log 10 because you invoked the function from the player object, and there is a property player.power and it equals 10.

//For contrast:  now make a variable in the global scope and store the same function to the new variable:

> let sameFunction = player.func;

//under the hood, the code above will be:

> window.sameFunction = player.function  or window.sameFunction = func:
>   function() { console.log(this.power);}
>
> sameFunction();

will log undefined because sameFunction is pointing to the function stored at player.func *BUT* you are invoking it from the global object, and that object does not have a property named power.

invoking sameFunction() is the same as invoking window.sameFunction() when window is the global object.  Your window object does not have a property named power;  so this.power is undefined.

(When you see the 'this' word used inside of function declarations, it is possibly a constructor function.  These functions are structured in order to create objects.  To use them, you have to understand the new keyword and what it does).